# copy all files from ftp folder using Chef

Tags: ftp, chef-infra

`remote_file` block copies only one specific file.
Is there any possibility in Chef to copy all files from specific folder on ftp?

my current code is quite weird as for me:

```
require 'net/ftp'
ftp = Net::FTP::new("server")
ftp.login("user", "password")
ftp.chdir("/folder")
fileList = ftp.nlst('*.jar')
fileList.each do |file|
  remote_file "C:\\Temp\\" + file do
    source "ftp://user:password@server/folder/" + file
    action :create_if_missing
  end
end
ftp.close
```

Answer (score 0):

If your solution works, why not wrap it in an `LWRP`? They are quite easy to create, and would tuck away the implementation in its own file. This is what I would do.

See: http://docs.opscode.com/chef/lwrps_custom.html

And for a real-life - easy to understand - example, see:

- https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/ssh_known_hosts/blob/master/providers/entry.rb
- https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/ssh_known_hosts/blob/master/resources/entry.rb